# Display ggplot legend correctly for line/shape combinations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot for three groups using three different coloured lines but only two of the groups have point markers. I can get the plot to display correctly but the legend shows the same point markers for all three groups.

I have created a reproducible example using the mpg dataset

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(mpg, drv != '4'), mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, shape = drv), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Variable", labels = c("4", "f", "r"), values=c("4" = "#DA2128", "f" = "black", "r" = "blue"))  +
  scale_shape_manual(name="Variable", labels = c("f", "r"), values = c("f" = 16, "r" = 17), guide = FALSE)
```

The group '4' should have no point marker in the legend and the group 'r' should show a triangle marker

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some alpha

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, shape = drv)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(alpha=drv), size = 3) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0,1,1)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,16, 17))
```

[image]

Or simply set shape `4`  to `NA`

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, shape = drv)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA, 16, 17)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#DA2128", "black", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works. Can I still set the individual colours manually?

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you've done now. Setting the alpha to 0 hides the point for one of the scales. Thanks again. Ignore my first comment I've set the colours with scale_color_manual and got the desired results.

Comment: Of course. You can simply add your `scale_color_manual(values=c("#DA2128", "black", "blue"))`. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `linetype` argument in your `geom_line()` with the variable of interest (`drv` in this case) gives your expected result.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, linetype = drv), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(mpg, drv != '4'), mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, shape = drv), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Variable", labels = c("4", "f", "r"), values=c("4" = "#DA2128", "f" = "black", "r" = "blue"))  +
  scale_shape_manual(name="Variable", labels = c("f", "r"), values = c("f" = 16, "r" = 17), guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This gives me two legends. One called drive with different line types and one called Variable which shows the same point marker for all three groups. I would like one legend showing the three groups with the correct line colours and markers as show on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable the legend for `shape` and set the values for `shape` manually in the `color` legend:

`ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(mpg, drv != '4'), mapping = aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = drv, shape = drv), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Variable", labels = c("4", "f", "r"), values=c("4" = "#DA2128", "f" = "black", "r" = "blue"), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c("4" = NA, "f" = 16, "r" = 17))))  +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("f" = 16, "r" = 17), guide=F)`

[image]

Comment: This also gets the desired results